# How to determine the AVERAGE number of associated records

Tags: sql, postgresql

**I have two tables:**

- reviews (id, created_at, completed_at, type)
- reviews_skills (id, review_id, note)

I have the following query that tells me What % of reviews have 1 or more notes.

```
SELECT  TRUNC(DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_DATE - r.created_at )/7)  AS weeks_ago,
        date(min(r.created_at)) AS "Date Start",
        date(max(r.created_at)) AS "Date End",
        count(*) as  "reviews in Cohort",
                AVG(has_note::int) as "Reviews w 1 or more Notes Ratio"
FROM (SELECT r.id, r.created_at,
             ( MAX(rs.note) IS NOT NULL ) as has_note
      FROM reviews r JOIN
           reviews_skills rs
           ON r.id = rs.review_id

            WHERE r.completed_at IS NOT NULL
                    AND r.created_at > '2019-01-01'
                    AND r.type = 'long_form'

            GROUP BY r.id
     ) f
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago DESC;
```

What I'm trying to add to this query is: **what is the AVG # of notes per review?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need the count in the subquery and then an average:

```
SELECT  TRUNC(DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_DATE - r.created_at )/7)  AS weeks_ago,
        date(min(r.created_at)) AS "Date Start",
        date(max(r.created_at)) AS "Date End",
        count(*) as  "reviews in Cohort",
        AVG(has_note::int) as "Reviews w 1 or more Notes Ratio",
          AVG(num_notes) as avg_notes
FROM (SELECT r.id, r.created_at,
             COUNT(rs.note) as num_notes,
             ( MAX(rs.note) IS NOT NULL ) as has_note
      FROM reviews r JOIN
           reviews_skills rs
           ON r.id = rs.review_id
      WHERE r.completed_at IS NOT NULL AND
            r.created_at > '2019-01-01' AND
            r.type = 'long_form'
      GROUP BY r.id
     ) f
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago DESC;
```